# MPI messages across libraries

Tags: mpi, openmpi, ms-mpi

Can you send MPI messages across two libraries?

Example - If I have MS-MPI installed on a windows machine and then Open-MPI on a linux cluster (Same Network), can I get messages between code running on the two different OS.

Basically multiple program multiple data MPMD but using Windows and Linux resources.

Just need to know if this is possible, and if so any info would be nice, but not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You will even get into great trouble if you try this with different versions or configurations of one implementation.

MPI is targeted at homogeneous installations on HPC systems. The communication protocol is not standardized, only the programming interface is.

Comment: Thanks.  Can find any packages that link any of these together either.  I am trying to find some way to get at least loose coupling between these resources.

Answer (score 0):

**In general:** no. This is not specified within the MPI standard, and most implementations do not support such jobs. It is a rather uncommon use case, I guess.

**However**, Intel MPI does provide cross-os launching of jobs, see:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/mpi-developer-guide-linux-cross-os-launch-mode

**Some detail:**
Intel MPI, as well as other commercial MPI implementations are based on the  MPICH open source project. I am not sure if cross-os launching can be achieved somehow via MPICH, though. A quick google research only provided negative, but possibly outdated results, e.g.

https://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/mpich2-dev/2005-July/000085.html